# C++ Splitting array of strings into subgroups

Tags: c++, arrays, split, grouping, divide

I have an array of string (which length is always different) and I need to split this into groups (which also number is different from time to time);

```
int main()
{
    // Array that I want to split;
    void Names = { Sara, Kaya, Hya, Jenny, Mary, Tiffany, Stefan };

    int groupNumber = 3;

    //Now I would like to split the names into 3 different groups as evenly as
    //possibile so that I can print
    // Group 1 : Sara,Hya,Jenny;
    //Group 2 : Kaya,Mary;
    //Group 3 : Tiffany, Stefan;
}
```

Comment: You cannot have an array of `void`. `void` is a keyword that represents the concept of "nothing".

Comment: There are a few things that need clarification: You used the word 'array' and this could mean std::array (`std::array<std::string, 7> a = { /* names */ }`), a C-style array (`std::string[] a = { /* names */ }`), a std::vector (`std::vector<std::string> a = { /* names */ }`) or perhaps something else.

Comment: The array of type `void` will not work. Additionally the content of this array does not work, since these are not strings.
Please provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: i'm not sure what your definition of "as evently as possible" is. to me `(Tiffany,Sara)(Stefan,Jenny)(Hya,Kaya,Mary)` looks more even.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code that splits the array into multiple groups. I hope it helps to get started.

```
int groupNumber = 3;
std::vector<std::string> names = { "Sara", "Kaya", "Hya", "Jenny", "Mary", "Tiffany", "Stefan" };
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> groups;
groups.resize(groupNumber);
for (int i= 0; i < names.size(); ++i)
{
    groups.at(i % groupNumber).push_back(names.at(i));
}
```

You can use this loop to print out the groups.

```
for (auto group : groups)
{
    for (auto name : group)
    {
        std::cout  << name << " , ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mzMe.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& stream, const std::vector<T>& vec) {
    stream << "{";
    for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it) {
        if (it != vec.begin()) stream << ", ";
        stream << *it;
    }
    stream << "}";
    return stream;
}

template <size_t GroupN, typename T> // T can be deduced
std::array<std::vector<T>, GroupN> split_vector(std::vector<T> vec_to_split) {
    std::array<std::vector<T>, GroupN> result;
    size_t remaining = vec_to_split.size();
    size_t optimal_size;
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < GroupN; ++i) {
        optimal_size = (remaining + GroupN - i - 1) / (GroupN - i);
        // ceiling division, 7/3->3, 4/2->2, 2/1->2
        result[i].reserve(optimal_size);
        for (size_t j = vec_to_split.size() - remaining; j < vec_to_split.size() - remaining + optimal_size; ++j)
            result[i].push_back(vec_to_split[j]);
        remaining -= optimal_size; // 7-3=4, 4-2=2, 2-2=0
    }
    
    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13};
    auto [v1, v2, v3] = split_vector<3>(v); // Structured binding, C++17 or above only
    cout << v1 << ", " << v2 << ", " << v3 << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The top function is just a pretty-printer for `std::vector` since they're not printable be default. I used `int` not `std::string`, but it doesn't matter,

The main function returns an array so its size is given at compile-time as a template argument.

Comment: I didn't use an array of arrays because that would make things a bit more complicated